# How to find (u,v) coordinates of center of inscribed circle on the Poincare plane?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I have three points with their coordinates (u1,v1) , (u2,v2) , (u3,v3) on the unit circle in Poincare model. Is there a formula giving coordinates of centre of inscribed circle in triangle builded on those three points?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).